# php - delete single record on single page form submit

Tags: php, forms

I'm pretty new to PHP, so please forgive me if this question is obnoxiously noob...

I have a page that lists close to 150 records from a database.  I want the user to only be able to delete one record at a time (no checkboxes).  I want there to be a delete button next to each name, and when the user clicks it, the page refreshes with the updated list and success message above saying: "%Name% was deleted successfully". (where %Name% is the actual name they deleted)

My question is: Can I do this with a form?  If so, what form element would I assign the Name and delete button to?

Or, do I need to set the delete button as an anchor element, with the URL set to a page that can process the delete request, then redirects the user back (my concern there is the only way I can send the "Success" message back, that I know of is through a Session variable, is that ok?)

Or, is there some other way completely that I don't know of?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it both way... here the key concept is having a unique field like id in the database for eg you have id,name,username and password field in database table so look at both the ways below

**1. using hyperlink**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("fostname","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name");
if(mysql_num_rows($q)>0)
{
echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><td>name</td><td>action</td></tr>";
while($name = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
?>

<tr><td><?php echo $name['name'];?></td><td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $name['id'];?>">Delete</a></td></tr>
<?php
}

echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

this is what you do in listing page.... now look at delete.php which needs to be on the path as defined in hyperlink

delete.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("fostname","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$q = mysql_query("delete from tbl_name where id = '$id'");
header("Location: list.php");
?>
```

**2. Using form**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("fostname","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("database_name");
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name");
    if(mysql_num_rows($q)>0)
    {
    echo"<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>name</td><td>action</td></tr>";
    while($name = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
    ?>

    <tr><td><?php echo $name['name'];?></td><td><form action='delete.php' method='post'> <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $name["id"];?>'></form></td></tr>
    <?php
    }

    echo "</table>";
    }
    ?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("fostname","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("database_name");
    $id = $_POSTs['id'];
    $q = mysql_query("delete from tbl_name where id = '$id'");
    header("Location: list.php");
    ?>
```

(note: list.php is the page where you list all the info)

Comment: Thanks for putting in the work and confirming that it's ok to create a form for each entry. And thank you VERY much for showing exactly which form elements to use.  I'll follow your example, but will submit it to the same page.  Just out of curiosity, in your example, the delete.php file doesn't have a way to send the "Success" message back to the list.php page.  How would you do that?  Session variable?

Comment: But if you are submitting in the same page dont forget to use if(isset($_POST['submit'])){/*form validation codes*/} and perform this on the top of the page.... otherwise you will get error.... for sending success message you can use this, header("Locattion: list.php?msg=success"); instead of last line of delete.php and then in the top of the page of list.php use if(isset($_GET['success'])){echo "success message";}..... thats it

Answer (score 1):

why does it have to be a/one form? You could use links to delete single entries like href="#?job=delete&name=name instead of a submit button. An other solution would be to create a form for each entry.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's ok to have a form for each entry.  I wasn't sure about this.  And probably will be the way I do it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP session is server side data that is kept on a user and kept track of via a cookie. The data isn't sent to the user unless you specifically send it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

You can have an individual form for each record on the page or a form that gets filled by clicking one of the records through javascript and submitted. You can either reload the page and tell the user if they were successful or send it via ajax and update pieces of the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

You can use straight javascript or something developed on top of js like jquery or moo tools to make things easier. Here is some data on the ajax function in jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As far as name and delete. Delete could be an input, button, image, whatever.. name could be the user id of the deleted record that would send back the name or simply taken from a part of the form to show the user which record was deleted.

There are a number of ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Very helpful, and I'm glad you were able to confirm that it's ok to have a form for each entry. I wasn't sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page (say A) that contain your data.

When you have it, you can "anchor" a link on the button for each element (assigning a costum id for identify it).
Once you click on the button, you add in the built-in array `$_GET` the id of the record that you have erased (obv. you have to erase it).
Now you can redirect to the same page (A).

On this page (that is the same page where you have initial data) you check for `$_GET` field that you added.
If it is that means that you come there after a delete and you can display the message.
Otherwise is the very first time you enter here, so you haven't to display nothing.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

make one form somewhere with a hidden field and no submit button, when the form submits it deletes the row with the given value. then when echoing all the rows, echo out a submit button next to each with an onlick of "submitForm(x)" where "X" is some value that can determine which row to delete in the db.